# script to copy particular files with the end character from one directory to another directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I am new to script,

I want to copy particular files from one directory to directory.

**Example:**

**c:\website to D:\website**

**C:\website contains:**

**flower_small.jpg**

**flower_large.jpg**

**flowerss_small.jpg**

**flowerss_large.jpg**

I want to copy all the files ends with '_small.jpg'

I have large number of files to move.

Can you please help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "source_folder=c:\website"
set "destination_folder=D:\website"

pushd "%source_folder%"

for %%a in (*_small.jpg) do (
    copy /y "%%a" "%destination_folder%" 
)
popd
endlocal
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: This should work, but it seems needlessly complex. A single COPY or XCOPY is all that should be needed.

Comment: @dbenham - yes.When I saw Scott C answer I gave myself a big slap to the forehead.. \:-/

Comment: thanks a lot.. it worked, also i have changed conditions and inserted some more codes it worked.. once again thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need:

`copy c:\website\*_small.jpg D:\website`

However, you did say you "have large number of files to move." If you really want to move them and not have the files in both directories. Then use:

`move c:\website\*_small.jpg D:\website`